# javafx: PieChart incorrect data handles MouseEvent

Tags: java, javafx-2, pie-chart

I just learned about JavaFX yesterday, and am now testing the graphing options. I noticed this behavior with the pie chart sample from the Oracle site (http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/pie-chart.htm), but I added more data points and some hover effects to make it more noticeable.

When you hover over the chart, the MouseEvent does not always get handled by the right data segment. The closer the mouse cursor to the center of the pie, the more pronounced this effect becomes. When near the edge, the behavior is accurate as far as I can tell.

Can anyone confirm this? Is this a bug, or something I am doing incorrectly?

Try moving the mouse, starting from a segment’s labeled edge, and move inward to the center and see if the segment under the cursor is correctly indicated.

[image: Screenshot of chart - mouse is where tooltip shows]

A couple of other things I noticed while playing with this chart –

1. The stroke effect (here a white dash) is not consistent on a
   segment. The left edge often looks clipped
2. How do you change the tooltip page-corner in java? In CSS it is “.page-corner“
3. Is there
   any way to change the shape of the pie-label-line, or remove the
   round endpoint all together?

Edit: forgot to add the code!

```
package piechartsample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Side;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.chart.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.effect.Glow;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeType;
import javafx.scene.Node;

public class PieChartSample extends Application {

    private PieChart.Data selectedData;
    private Tooltip tooltip;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData =
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new PieChart.Data("Grapefruit", 13),
                new PieChart.Data("Orange", 25),
                new PieChart.Data("Plum", 10),
                new PieChart.Data("Pear", 22),
                new PieChart.Data("Banana", 10),
                new PieChart.Data("Peach", 5),
                new PieChart.Data("Apricot", 1),
                new PieChart.Data("Pineapple", 20),
                new PieChart.Data("Passion Fruit", 100),
                new PieChart.Data("Lychee", 5));

        final PieChart chart = new PieChart(pieChartData);
        chart.setTitle("Fruits Graph");
        chart.setLabelLineLength(10);
        chart.setLegendSide(Side.LEFT);

        final Label caption = new Label("");
        caption.setTextFill(Color.DARKORANGE);
        caption.setStyle("-fx-font: 24 arial;");

        tooltip = new Tooltip("");

        tooltip.setStyle("-fx-font: 14 arial;  -fx-font-smoothing-type: lcd;");// -fx-text-fill:black; -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#e2ecfe, #99bcfd);");


        for (final PieChart.Data data : chart.getData()) {
            Tooltip.install(data.getNode(),tooltip);
            applyMouseEvents(data);
        }

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setCenter(chart);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        stage.setTitle("Fruits");
        stage.setScene(scene);
//        scene.getStylesheets().add("piechartsample/Chart.css");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private void applyMouseEvents(final PieChart.Data data) {

        final Node node = data.getNode();

        node.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
                node.setEffect(new Glow());
                String styleString = "-fx-border-color: white; -fx-border-width: 3; -fx-border-style: dashed;";
                node.setStyle(styleString);
                tooltip.setText(String.valueOf(data.getName() + "\n" + (int)data.getPieValue()) ); 
            }
        });

        node.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
                node.setEffect(null);
                node.setStyle("");
            }
        });

        node.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                    selectedData = data;
                    System.out.println("Selected data " + selectedData.toString());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PieChart incorrect picking behaviour for MouseEvent

For your particular implementation, I experienced no picking problems with the slice regions when using JavaFX 2.2.

Picking errors for pie chart slice regions would seem to be a known issue. The issue would appear to be [partially fixed](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-22954) for JavaFX 2.2 (jdk7u6). There is an [outstanding issue](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-22987) related to this scheduled for JavaFX 3.0. Anybody can sign up for access to view the linked jira issues in this answer.

The [JavaFX 2.2 developer preview](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html) is available here.

---

> How do you change the tooltip page-corner in java?

The [JavaFX css reference guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) provides info on the css structure of a tooltip.  This shows you that the substructure has the class .page-corner.  To see how the JavaFX default caspian skin styles the page corner you can review [caspian.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.2/master/rt/raw-file/tip/javafx-ui-controls/src/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.css).  The link in this answer is to the 2.2 version.  You can also extract caspian.css for you JavaFX installation from jfxrt.jar if you need to.

Once you have caspian.css you can search for Tooltip to see the specific styling applied to the .page-corner css class.  Here is the default .page-corner styling =>

```
.page-corner {
  -fx-padding: 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5;
  -fx-background-color: linear-gradient( from 0% 0% to 50% 50%, #fcf7b6, #a59c31);
  -fx-shape: "M0,0H9L0,9Z";
  -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.6) , 4 , 0.0 , 0 , 0 );
}
```

To change the default styling, load your own user css stylesheet with your specific definition for the page corner.  For example, the following styleclass definition will turn the page corner into a glowing green pac-man.

```
.page-corner {
  -fx-padding: 10;
  -fx-background-color: green;
  -fx-shape: "M30,20 h-15 a15,15 0 1,0 15,-15 z";
  -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , derive(green, 40%), 10, 0.0 , 0 , 0 );
}
```

---

> Is there any way to change the shape of the pie-label-line, or remove the round endpoint all together?

Yes, but it is not entirely straightforward.

It would seem that the pie-label-line is a implemented single Path which is styled via:

```
.chart-pie-label-line {
  -fx-stroke: #aaaaaa;
  -fx-fill: #aaaaaa;
}
```

To change the shape of the Path, you could either could do a lookup on the label line after the chart has been displayed and write some code which removed the ball element from it; e.g. `(Path) chart.lookup(".chart-pie-label-line")` OR you could subclass PieChart and override the `layoutChartChildren` method.  Lines 670-6 in this version of the [PieChart source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.2/master/rt/file/218e7d2c04da/javafx-ui-charts/src/javafx/scene/chart/PieChart.java) are the ones which generate the label line.

---

> The stroke effect (here a white dash) is not consistent on a segment. The left edge often looks clipped

The clipping is because you are applying the border to the pie chart slice node and the pie chart is internally laid out such that latter items added to the chart overlay earlier ones.  When you add a thick border, then (with the exception of the last slice drawn) the border will be overlapped by the next pie slice drawn.  You can get around this by calling [node.toFront()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#toFront%28%29) in your mouse entered method.

However there are other offset issues with the stroke where it should align over the pie slice better.  If the stroke width is set 1, it aligns fine, if it is set to a larger number like 10 it ends up not aligning.  My guess is this is some bug in the css processing of the border style and would encourage to sign up for an account and log a [jira issue](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com) regarding this in the JavaFX issue tracker.

---

Probably would have been better to post some of your other questions not related to the question title as separate stackoverflow questions.

Comment: Thanks jewelsea for your your assistance. It's good to know that the picking issue is a known bug - I looked at the change log and saw it was a simple fix http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.2/controls/rt/diff/480b6f9324a7/javafx-ui-charts/src/javafx/scene/chart/PieChart.java. Unfortunately, I want to stick with an official release so my users have access to the same version, so I will need to wait until 2.2 is released. (Sorry about the additional questions, I figured out most of them on my own, but it's frustrating how limited the API is currently. Not ready for prime-time yet.)

Comment: Also, I don't know how other people feel about this, but I am incredibly turned off by the requirement to sign up for an account to view the jira issues, as well as another separate account to download the 2.2 preview. Despite the fact that the mercurial codebase is freely viewable.